# RSpec Capybara - Request test. Need advise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

Two things which i don't understand at all.

1) first example:  **visit path** - fail and **get path** - pass, why?
Visit - capybara and get - rspec helper, right?

```
  describe "in the Users controller" do
   describe "visiting the users page as non-signed" do
     before { get users_path }
     #before { visit users_path }
     it { expect(response.status).to eql(302) }
     it { expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path) }
   end
   describe "visiting the user[:id = 1] profile page as non-signed" do
     before { get user_path(User.where(admin: true)) }
     #before { visit user_path(User.where(admin: true)) }
     it { expect(response.status).to eql(302) }
     it { expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)  }
   end
 end
```

With **get some_path_here**  -> test pass

But with **visit some_path_here** ->

[image]

2) second example:

after login as regular user, should not have menu like admin. 
It looks like **no differense between user and admin**

```
  describe "as signed admin" do
    let(:admin) { create(:admin) }
    before do
      log_in admin
    end
    it { should have_link("Users", href: users_path)}
    it { should have_link("Orders", href: orders_path)}
    it { should have_link("Current Menu", href: products_path)}
    it { should_not have_link("Dashboard", href: new_order_path)}
  end

  describe "as signed user" do
    let(:user) { create(:user) }
      before do
        log_in user
      end
    it { should have_link("Profile", href: user_path(user))}
    it { should have_link("Dashboard", href: new_order_path)}
    it { should_not have_link("Users", href: users_path)}
    it { should_not have_link("Current Menu", href: products_path)}
  end


include ApplicationHelper

def log_in(user)
 visit root_path
 fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
 fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
 click_button 'Sign in'
end
def sign_up(user)
  visit new_user_registration_path
 fill_in 'Username', with: user.username
 fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
 fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
 fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: user.password
 click_button 'Sign up'
end
```

[image]

**EDIT 1**

I do like that..and i can't get it...what's wrong with that..?

```
let(:admin) { create(:admin) }
let(:user) { create(:user) }

factory :user do
  sequence(:username)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
  sequence(:email)     { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
  password              "qwerty"
  password_confirmation "qwerty"

  factory :admin do
   admin true
  end
end
```

and my view

```
- if user_signed_in?
%ul.nav.navbar-nav
  %li
    =link_to "Profile", current_user
  - if !current_user.admin?
    #if !current_user.try(:admin?)
    %li
      =link_to "Dashboard", new_order_path
    - if !Order.get_order_for_user(current_user).nil?
      %li
        %a{:href => order_path(Order.get_order_for_user current_user)} Order
  - else
    %li
      %a{:href => users_path} Users
    %li
      %a{:href => orders_path } Orders
    %li
      %a{:href => products_path } Current Menu
%ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
  %li
    = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method =>  :delete
it looks fine for me,but maybe i miss something...
```

**EDIT 2**

short version of db/shcema:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.boolean  "admin"
  end
```

and my User model:

```
 before_save :set_default_role

  private
  # Set first user as Admin
  def set_default_role
    if User.count == 0
      self.admin = true
    end
  end
```

**EDIT 3 - last one! ;)**

i save my  before_save :set_default_role

but in my test, i do that:

```
  # User model -> before_save make first user admin.
  let(:admin) { create(:user) }
  let(:non_admin) { create(:user) }
  before do
    sign_up admin
    log_in non_admin
  end
```

*I understand it can be not ideal, but it works and that's fine for my prog.level. But if somebody have BP solution i will take that notice ;)*

Comment: Please post your test traces in the text format.

Comment: `user_path` routes to users show.  I.e. singular, `User.where(admin: true)` will return a collection not a single user.

Comment: @j-dexx, it doesn't metter because in db always only 1 user.

Comment: @mix-fGt it does matter.  There is a difference between having a user object and having a collection with one user in it.

Comment: @j-dexx, agree! Thanks for the notice. fixed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) When using Capybara you use `visit` and `page`, when using plain rails integration tests (which RSpec request specs are a wrapper around) you use `get` and `response`  - you can't mix and match those like using `visit` and `response` together.  Also, in Capybara most drivers don't provide access to things like request response codes and whether or not the page was redirected since it's designed to test from a users perspective, which implies replying only on things that appear in the browser.

2) From your errors it appears a normal user is behaving exactly like an admin user which could be caused be a few things depending on what you're actually doing on the page.  The simplest explanation would be that your conditional check for whether or not the user is an admin isn't implemented correctly, either in your model, or in the logic you have in your view.

Comment: @mix-fGt If the admin and user are still behaving the same, take a look at your definition of User#admin? and also at the user/admin factories.

Comment: I will check that too,thk. I had almost same problem when i check access for action - before action. Using devise helper methods. But now, how you said - check model or view. In view I do that:  if !current_user.admin?  and then show regular menu  else -> admin menu. what do you think about that?

Comment: @mix-fGt That should be fine as long as User#admin? is defined correctly - and the :user factory isn't creating admins accidentally

Comment: Can you check my answer pls.

Comment: @mix-fGt It looks right to me assuming your admin column is boolean and doesn't default to true.  Also, do you define your own User#admin? method or use the one provided automatically by rails?

Comment: I made EDIT 2 in my question. When i do: `Factory.create(:admin)` and then `login admin` - that logic about set admin doesn't meter or am i wrong..?

Comment: @mix-fGt Yes that matters -- it's making the first user you create in every test an admin - which is why your "normal" user is acting like an admin (they are one).  Remove the `before_save :set_default_role` and your tests will work.

Comment: Nice one!))) Thank you,rly. But this `before_save :set_default_role` need because first user became admin.This was a conscious decision...         So what i suppose to do? Mby create(:user) ->became -> admin and second user -> regular user?))

Comment: thank's  for your detailed explanation, I'm really appreciated!

Comment: @mix-fGt You could create two every time, or move the first user is an admin logic to the user controllers create action - so it doesn't affect your factories